# How are ECDSA signatures computed for X509 Certificates?

Tags: certificates, digital-signature, sha, x.509, ecc

I am trying to verify a certificate signature on my own. To do this, I created a self-signed certificate using OpenSSL with the two following command lines:

> openssl ecparam -name secp256k1 -genkey -param_enc explicit -out
>   private-key.pem
>
> openssl req -new -x509 -key private-key.pem -out
>   server.pem -days 730

[You can take a look at my certificate here.](http://www.lapo.it/asn1js/#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)

I can clearly distinguish the public key and the signature which respectively are:

**public key**

> 93 99 FD 9F 7F 04 48 AF 51 2C  6D 2D 69 04 B9 1F 88 A9 C2 64 31 8E 68
>   70 5B 55  C8 63 C2 C3 AC A4 17 BD 89 1A 5E 8E 08 C4 B7 92  AD AF 51 28
>   D3 AC BC CE 73 FA 5D D2 FE A7 EB 53  C7 6E 1A 00 84 2C

**signature**

> 32 BA FB EB A8  E9 BB 4B 2D 2B 19 12 65 11 EC BB F5 46 5E B5 59  3A 9D
>   42 F2 62 74 BA A0 E7 73 03
>   E1 4C  CE 67 2B 7D 3B BA 75 E9 8B 95 95 57 E7 17 B7 C1  99 4B 71 96
>   74 89 67 5F DC B1 0C 71 3B 5F

My problem is that I don't understand **what is the input of the signature algorithm** (ECDSA with SHA256)?

I tried to verify the signature by performing ECC computations on a hash (SHA256) of all the data before the signature TLV (*i.e.* all except 
03 48 00 30 45 02 20 32 BA FB EB A8  E9 BB 4B 2D 2B 19 12 65 11 EC BB F5 46 5E B5 59  3A 9D 42 F2 62 74 BA A0 E7 73 03 02 21 00 E1 4C  CE 67 2B 7D 3B BA 75 E9 8B 95 95 57 E7 17 B7 C1  99 4B 71 96 74 89 67 5F DC B1 0C 71 3B 5F) but it seems that the signature is not valid with this input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The signature is computed over the `tbsCertificate` (To-Be-Signed) data.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.1:

```
Certificate  ::=  SEQUENCE  {
    tbsCertificate       TBSCertificate,
    signatureAlgorithm   AlgorithmIdentifier,
    signatureValue       BIT STRING  }
```

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.1.1.3 says:

> 

The signatureValue field contains a digital signature computed upon
the ASN.1 DER encoded tbsCertificate.  The ASN.1 DER encoded
tbsCertificate is used as the input to the signature function.  This
signature value is encoded as a BIT STRING and included in the
signature field.  The details of this process are specified for each
of the algorithms listed in [RFC3279], [RFC4055], and [RFC4491].

> By generating this signature, a CA certifies the validity of the
> information in the tbsCertificate field.  In particular, the CA
> certifies the binding between the public key material and the subject
> of the certificate.

So, the trivial version of what you got wrong is that you also need to exclude the leading `30 82 03 02`.  And you didn't trim enough off of the end.  Namely, the `30 0A 06 ...` part (the signature algorithm identifier).

But, using that already shown ASN/DER parsing, you see that the root SEQUENCE contains three children. The signature is over the first child only.

Comment: This site is really helpful to visualize the details: http://www.lapo.it/asn1js/